# ValidationError: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

```
    this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
                               ^

ValidationError: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required.
    at Document.invalidate (C:\Users\vicdh\SlayerLegendUpdates\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3200:32)
    at C:\Users\vicdh\SlayerLegendUpdates\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2993:17
    at C:\Users\vicdh\SlayerLegendUpdates\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1368:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  errors: {
    password: ValidatorError: Path `password` is required.
        at validate (C:\Users\vicdh\SlayerLegendUpdates\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1365:13)
        at SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Users\vicdh\SlayerLegendUpdates\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1349:7)
        at C:\Users\vicdh\SlayerLegendUpdates\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2985:18
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
      properties: {
        validator: [Function (anonymous)],
        message: 'Path `password` is required.',
        type: 'required',
        path: 'password',
        fullPath: undefined,
        value: undefined
      },
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'password',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'User validation failed'
}
```

model: user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
  },
});


// set up pre-save middleware to create password
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  try {
    // Check if the password field is modified and not empty
    if (this.isModified('password') && this.password) {
      const saltRounds = 10;
      this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, saltRounds);
    }
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error); // Pass error to the next middleware
  }
});

// Method to compare the incoming password with the hashed password
userSchema.methods.isCorrectPassword = async function(password) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};



const Users = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = Users;
```

schemas: resolvers.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user: async () => { 
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne();
        if(user){
          return console.log('User found: ', user);
        }
        const successful = console.log('User found: ', user);
        res.status(200).json(successful);
        return user;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('Error fetching user data');
      }
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    signup: async (_, { username, password }) => {
      try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        const user = await User.create({ username, password: hashedPassword })
        const savedUser = await User.save(); 
        const successful =console.log('User created: ', user);
        res.status(200).json(savedUser + successful);
        return user;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Error creating user');
      }
    },
    login: async (_, { username, password }) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ username});
        if (!user) {
          throw new Error('User not found');
        }
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, User.password);
        if (passwordMatch === false) {
          throw new Error("incorrect password " + console.log(passwordMatch) + console.log(user.password) + console.log(Error));
        } else if (passwordMatch === true){
          console.log(passwordMatch);
        }
           console.log('Login successful');
        return user;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(console.error('Error logging in: ', error));
      }
    }
  }
}
module.exports = resolvers;
```

schemas: typeDefs.js

```
const typeDefs = `
  type User {
    username: String
    password: String
  }

  type Query {
    user: User
  }

  type Mutation {
    signup(
      username: String!,
      password: String!
    ): User

    login(
      username: String!,
      password: String!
    ): User
  }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

Where am I going wrong? I can't seem to pinpoint the error. When i remove the required: true, I end up getting this `Could not connect to MongoDB MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` So I do not know if they are related or not. But in my opinion i believe the MongoDB one seems to be related to with some error in the server.js or connection.js file. I've tried doing throw new Error and console logging errors.

Dependencies/DevDependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.7.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
```

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/BlackisDay/SlayerLegendUpdates)

Comment: While completely unrelated, looking at [your repo here](https://github.com/BlackisDay/SlayerLegendUpdates/tree/main), you should add any and all dependencies to `package.json`. According to the latest [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html), to create a new model you should use the `new User()` syntax. I am not sure what `User.create()` does, but I wonder if you are bypassing something important by not using the recommended syntax.

If you are not using latest `8.x`, please provide the version you are on.

Comment: These are the server sided dependencies used,  ```"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.7.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.2"
  },```

Comment: the .create can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)